# Zend_DB_Select : why are all fields returned?

Tags: zend-framework, select, zend-db

```
public function getWorksheetData($id) {

/** create the following query using select object:

    SELECT wc.label, wd.notes FROM worksheet_data wd
    LEFT JOIN worksheet_columns wc ON wd.column_id = wc.id;

*/
    $id = (int) $id;

    $select = $this->_db->select()
    ->from(array('wd'=>'worksheet_data'),
            array('wc.label','wd.notes'))
    ->join(array('wc'=>'worksheet_columns','wd.column_id = wc.id'))
    ->where("wd.id = :worksheet_id");

    $results = $this->_db->fetchAll($select, array('worksheet_id' => $id),Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);


    return array('results'=>$results);
```

}

Why does this query become:

SELECT `wc`.`label`, `wd`.`notes`, `wc`.* FROM `worksheet_data` AS `wd` INNER JOIN `worksheet_columns` AS `wc` WHERE (wd.id = :worksheet_id)

and return wc.*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put an empty array as the third argument to the join method, also the join condition should not be part of the first argument's array, but as the second argument instead (you'll notice that there is not join condition in your query). Join needs at least the first two arguments, this is the method signature:

> join(table, join, [columns])

Applying that to your join method:

```
->join(array('wc'=>'worksheet_columns'),'wd.column_id = wc.id', array())
```

so:

```
$select = $this->_db->select()
        ->from(array('wd'=>'worksheet_data'),
                        array('wc.label','wd.notes'))
        ->join(array('wc'=>'worksheet_columns'),'wd.column_id = wc.id', array())
        ->where("wd.id = :worksheet_id");
```

gives the output:

```
SELECT `wc`.`label`, `wd`.`notes` FROM `worksheet_data` AS `wd` INNER JOIN `worksheet_columns` AS `wc` ON wd.column_id = wc.id WHERE (wd.id = :worksheet_id)
```

The [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) says:

> To select no columns from a table, use
>   an empty array for the list of
>   columns.

Comment: Thanks. the manual also says joinInner(table, join, [columns]) methods. Don't the square brackets mean that is optional?

Comment: @codecowboy - yes it does, I've added the method signature to my answer.